# Enforcing multiple forms of authentication on a single operation

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm creating an API that I am going to put behind Azure's API Management.  To secure API Management -> API, I am going to use certificate authentication.  On top of that, I want to use JWT bearer tokens.  I know I can use API Management's policies to validate the bearer token, but I like having the validation in the code as it's less to redo if we move away from Azure.  With that in mind, I did the following to my controller:

```
[Authorize(Global.Constants.AppConfiguration.CertificatePolicyName)]
[Authorize(Global.Constants.AppConfiguration.BearerPolicyName)]
public class RedactedHub : HubBase<Redacted>
```

This appears to do a "OR" rather than the "AND" that I was looking for.  Is the only way to enforce an "AND" to create a custom auth policy that validates both or is there an OOTB approach?

I am using asp.net core 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I can use AuthorizationPolicyBuilder, which has a Combine operation for just what I want.  It means I'll need to decorate each controller/hub/op specifically, but that's fine.  Gets me pretty much what I was looking for.